# How to calculate the total energy of a planet at rest?

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, potential-energy, celestial-mechanics

Let's just say we have the Earth-Moon system isolated in space, with Earth at rest, and the moon orbiting it.
How can we calculate the *total* energy of Earth in such a case (Kinetic energy would be effectively negligible I'm assuming, hence only potential energy would be taken into account?)?

We can calculate the Energy of the Moon using the equation:

### Total = Kinetic + Potential

But how would one calculate the *total* energy of a body at rest (Earth in this case)?

Comment: There are different kinds of energy.  If you just mean gravitational energy of an assembled sphere, you might take a look at https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SphereGravitationalPotentialEnergy.html

Comment: In such system Earth is not at rest, but is orbiting the common center of mass of the system Moon+Earth. Kinetic energy of Earth is not zero - it orbits and also rotates.

Comment: @JánLalinský well, true that's why I used the words 'effectively negligible' kinetic energy not absolutely.